# Phases for mobile game development

Tags: java-me, bluetooth

I'm currently thinking of developing chess code with multi-player facility connected and played via bluetooth. For that I need to chalk out the phases, i mean systematic modules, that I should follow to develop the game. If anyone can state it or have any link that can help it out, it would be great.

Another thing I am developing this in J2ME, so can anyone give me an idea about the way to connect the game in two mobile devices through bluetooth in J2ME. I mean to say the class or file that is used to connect the gaming devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the second part of your question: you need to make an SPP (serial) connection between the two devices, with one acting as a client and the other as a server; see [this tutorial](http://www.jsr82.com/jsr-82-sample-spp-server-and-client/#more-22) for more information.

Then you need to create your own protocol to allow the two devices to communicate everything they need to.

This will only work on handsets with [JSR 82](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr082/allclasses-frame.html).